# 1kHz Laser Detection

Tags: filter, laser, detection

Has anyone got an ideas about how these guys made this system?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlyVThcNRE4

I think they are using a 555 timer to power the laser at 1kHz. But then I don't know how they are using the bandpass filter and the solar cell.

I'm asking as I am involved with a similar project but I have no experience in electrical bandpass filters.

Comment: You should add more text to the question here instead of requesting others to watch that video. Without context it's not clear whether you're talking about a detection rate of 1 kHz or whether these guys falsely call a 1 kHz EM source "laser"

Answer (score 6):

They use a solar cell as a photo-detector and it looks like they modulate the laser with a square wave at 1kHz.

After the solar cell, the signal connects through a bandpass filter to "reject" dc (from sunlight) and all frequencies other than those close to 1kHz. The square wave now looks like a sinewave (because of the filtering) and this can be seen on the oscilloscope.

They seem to imply (in the written words below the video) that they have "tightened" the bandwidth of the low pass filter using a phase locked loop (PLL). I suspect they are using a switch-capacitor filter at this point because of the mention of the PLL.

This improvement will give a much tighter pass-band and once "something" is detected, the PLL will produce a multiple of the 1kHz (maybe 64kHz) to clock the switched capacitor filter.

Another advantage of using a PLL is that if the originating frequency drifts slightly, the PLL can be set to track it. So, if it drops down to 990Hz, the PLL will produce 63.36kHz and keep the switching filter "in tune".

The PLL might also set limits for upper and lower "acceptable" modulation frequencies. This is another advantage using this method.

A great switched capacitor filter is [this](http://www.linear.com/product/LTC1068) part, the LTC1068 as recommended to me by Anindo Ghosh.

Comment: How can the solar cell detect the frequencies though? I thought the solar cells just output a voltage as a result of the photons hitting the cell?

Comment: They do exactly that - while the photons are hitting the cell. When the laser is on you get more power output than when it's off.

Comment: @user29176 If you held a solar cell to a fluorescent tube and looked at the output on an oscilloscope you'd see AC power frequencies. The light from the laser is modulated at 1kHz (20 times higher than ac power) and you will see that modulation. OK at some point, the reactivity of the solar cell (its ability to change its output) will reduce and maybe at 1kHz it's only half as good as at 50 or 60Hz but still signals get through.

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with the output from the solar cell. This is made up from the voltage signal produced by the Sun, the environment (reflections/shadows, clouds, birds, people, buildings etc.), electrical noise and of course the laser pulse.

The Sun will produce a time varying DC signal. Superimposed on that will be the smaller fluctuations due to noise, other light sources and the laser pulses.

What is required is to pull out the small signal 'noise' and detect the presence or absence of the 1kHz signal.

[image]

The first step is to eliminate the large DC component from the signal. This is done by passing the signal through a high pass filter (pass only the higher frequencies).  Since the laser frequency is known (1kHz) a low pass filter can be used to reduce the value of frequencies above 1kHz (a low pass filter lets through the lower frequencies). The combination of a high pass and low pass filter produces a band pass filter. This can be realized with simple CR and RC circuits. By choosing suitable values the filter can 'tuned' to the required frequency. (1000 (Hz) = 1/2*pi*C*R). These simple circuit produces a 1st order filter. (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter )

Passive filters introduce a loss of signal. Better filters (narrower band (higher Q), amplification etc.) can be designed using active devices (op-amps, transistor, dedicated filter ICs etc.).

The filter process can also be accomplished by using software/micro controller which could also be used to lock onto the signal and track it.
[image]

Comment: Thats great thanks JIm,. I have just purchased an arduino board, and i'm hoping to find a way to programme a band pass filter into  it

Comment: Has anyone any idea how these guys used the waveform to light up the LED? I guess the signal with create some voltage from the solar cell, but would this be enough to directly power a LED? It looks to me like there is a rectifier circuit to convert the signal to DC?

Comment: @user29176 Once the signal is filtered you need to detect if it is present or absent. In hardware this would be amplified (if needed), rectified, smoothed and compared to a DC reference value with the output of the comparator used to turn the LED on or off.  In software its a logical test of the presence or absence of signal and turn an output pin on or off.